How were seismic wave velocities measured on Mars with only one station?
The Insight lander touched down on Mars in 2018. It deployed its seismometer and gathered 4 years of data. Recently, a paper was published which, based on Insight data combined with modeling, concluded that "A mid-crust composed of fractured igneous rocks saturated with liquid water best explains the existing data." Naturally this has made a splash in the news. The raw data consists of measurements (or estimates?) of the S-wave and P-wave seismic velocities and the bulk density. Not being a seismologist, I don't understand how one can measure a velocity with a single station. Can someone explain, or refer me to a source understandable to someone (like me) with a good grounding in physics but none in seismology?
The paper is "Liquid water in the Martian mid-crust", Wright et al, 2024, PNAS, Vol. 121 No. 35. It can be found at https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2409983121

Cross-posting of https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/measuring-seismic-velocity-with-insight-landers-single-seismometer

Seismic waves keep going round and round (while decaying in amplitude). We now how far around it is.

In short - there are many types of seismic waves that spread in a planetary medium after a seismic event. P-waves, S-waves, Love's waves, etc. Every type of wave have different speed of spreading in a given medium. Observing many types of seismic waves from MANY sesismic events makes possible to deduct a model of Martian interior even with single station. You can start with Wikipedia-Seismology.

Maybe this question and my answer can be useful https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30473/25911

different, but related: How are marsquake epicenters determined using only one seismometer?

"this has made a splash in the news" :-)

Thanks to everybody for the information. It sounds to me like with enough data, you can fit a model of the interior which has variables for the layer thicknesses and the rock properties (such as seismic wave propagation speed). In this case, the model included a variable for the water content of the rocks in the layer 10-20 km down.
